# How about boolean formula that is satisfied on every reject path and falsified on every accept path of non deterministic Turing machine?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability, nondeterminism, polynomial-time

Cook-Levin reduction is both deterministic polynomial time and parsimonious and that's mean that from every non deterministic Turing machine $M$ and string $w$ it is possible in polynomial time deterministically to create the boolean formula $\alpha_{M,w}$ so that every **satisfying** assignment of $\alpha_{M,w}$ is **accepting** path/route of $M$ with input $w$ and every **falsifying** assignment of $\alpha_{M,w}$ is **rejecting** path/route of $M$ with input $w$, and also $\alpha_{M,w}$ is in conjunctive normal form.

Therefore $\alpha_{M,w}$ is **satisfiable** if and only if $M$ with input $w$ has **accept** path/route and $\alpha_{M,w}$ is **falsifiable** if and only if $M$ with input $w$ has **reject** path/route.

I think that it is also possible from every non deterministic Turing machine $M$ and string $w$ it is also possible in polynomial time deterministically to create the boolean formula $\beta_{M,w}$ so that every **satisfying** assignment of $\beta_{M,w}$ is **rejecting** path/route of $M$ with input $w$ and every **falsifying** assignment of $\beta_{M,w}$ is **accepting** path/route of $M$ with input $w$ and $\beta_{M,w}$ will be also in conjunctive normal form.

Therefore $\beta_{M,w}$ is **satisfiable** if and only if $M$ with input $w$ has **reject** path/route and $\beta_{M,w}$ is **falsifiable** if and only if $M$ with input $w$ has **accept** path/route.

Am I right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just what you'd get if you applied Cook-Levin to a machine that calculated the negation of $M$, e.g. you simulate $M$ and reject if it accepts and accept if it rejects. Basically, you can just swap the sense of "accept" and "reject".

Comment: This sounds like finding the complement of non deterministic Turing machine, that is non deterministic Turing machine that decides the complement of the language that the original non deterministic Turing machine decides. Did you mean to swap the "accept" and "reject" **paths** and **routes**?

Comment: I meant the special states that signal acceptance or rejection. I believe this does correspond to what you mean by swapping the "accept" and "reject" paths/routes. An accepting path/route is presumably an execution that terminates in the special "accept" state, and similarly for "reject". I do *not* mean changing what we mean by a non-deterministic TM accepting an *input* which is that there is *some* accepting path. If we do what I described in the previous comment, the new machine accepts an input if there is *some* rejecting path in the original machine. This is not the complement.

Comment: I understood you.

Comment: Sorry, but we're not here to check proofs that you've produced. Go carefully through what you've written and try to justify every single statement.